# How can I scrape a website with invalid HTML

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website that has invalid HTML.  [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parses it but loses some info because of how its handling the invalid HTML.  The built-in DOM parser with DOMXPath isn't working, it returns a blank result set.  I was able to get it (DOMDocument and DOMXPath) working locally after running the fetched HTML through PHP Tidy but PHP Tidy isn't installed on the server and its a shared hosting server, so I have no control over that.  I tried [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) but that just seems to be for securing user input, since it completely removes the doctype, head, and body tags.

Is there any kind of standalone alternative to PHP Tidy?  I would really prefer to use DOMXPath to navigate around and grab what I need, it just seems to need some help cleaning the HTML up before it can parse it.

Edit:  Im scraping this website: http://courseschedules.njit.edu/index.aspx?semester=2010f.  For now I'm just trying to get all the course links.

Comment: What website are you scraping?

Comment: That post actually had what I needed.  PHPQuery did the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM handles broken HTML fine if you use `loadHTML` or `loadHTMLFile`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://courseschedules.njit.edu/index.aspx?semester=2010f');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xPath->query('//div[@class="courseList_section"]//a');
foreach($links as $link) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $link->nodeValue, $link->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

will output

```
ACCT - Accounting (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=ACCT)
AD   - Art and Design (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=AD  )
ARCH - Architecture (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=ARCH)
... many more ...
TRAN - Transportation Engr (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=TRAN)
TUTR - Tutoring (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=TUTR)
URB  - Urban Systems (index.aspx?semester=2010f&subjectID=URB )
```

Using

```
echo $dom->saveXML($link), PHP_EOL;
```

in the `foreach` loop will output the full `outerHTML` of the links.

Comment: This does a little better than Simple HTML DOM Parser but if you count the results, it only gives 107 of the 123 links.

Comment: @Telanor updated. The XPath now searches for *all links inside divs with the class courseList_section* instead of for *all links inside spans inside divs*. I am pretty sure you could have fixed that easily yourself though. Also possible `'//a[ancestor::div[@class="courseList_section"]]'`

Comment: You're right, it does work now.  I'm still not sure how I didn't already try this.  That's actually the same XPath query I was using locally after running Tidy

Answer (score 0):

if you know the errors you might apply some regular expressions to fix them specifically. While this ad-hoc solution might seem dirty, it may actually be better as if the HTML is indeed malformed it might be complex to infer a correct interpretation automatically.

EDIT: Actually it might be better to simply extract the needed information through regular expressions as the page has many errors which would be hard or at least tedious to fix.

Comment: -1. It seems dirty because it's difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a web service that will run your content through Tidy?  Could you write one?  Tidy is the only sane way I know of fixing broken markup.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to solve the problem could be passing the site you are trying to scrape through a mobile browser adapter package such as google's mobilizer for complicated websites. This will correct the invalid html and enable you to use the simple html dom parser package, but it might not work if you need some of the information that is stripped out of the site. The links to this adapter are below. I use this for sites on which the information is poorly formatted or if I need a way to simplify the formatting so that it is easy to parse. The html returned by the google mobilizer is simpler and much easier to process.

http://www.google.com/gwt/n