# PHP Regex running well - now i need some tailoring

Tags: php

Good evening dear community,

i need some help with preg_match - i want to optimize the code that allready runs very well!  i want to get ony the results  - not the overhead of HTML-tags in the result
That means i have to tailor the regex a bit. How can i improve the (allready very nice) code!?

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("< - URL - >");

var_dump($content);

$pattern = '/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/si';
preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    $match = strip_tags($match);
    $match = trim($match);
    var_dump($match);
}

?>
```

See here the url: [link text](http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=348.4490857628354&SchulAdresseMapDO=142426)

Hmm - i need to tailor the regex a bit... Cany anybody give me.

Each idea and tipp will be greatly appreciated
regards
zero

Comment: Could you explain what you're looking for? Same output but faster processing? Different output?

Comment: Yeah, what's your question about exactly?

Comment: well the html is invalid. I need to have a good regex or another approach - that gives a starting point! Well - the regex i have does not fit 100%. Hmmm in perl there is a way to strip the Table-Tags... isn t´it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to scrape data from HTML pages. If this is the case, then you really should not use regular expressions to extract information. Take a look instead at the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

Note that `DOMDocument` requires XML input, so often a "tidying" process needs to prepare the HTML for being parsed as XML. One convenient way to do this is to use the ["tidy" extension](http://php.net/tidy). See "[Tidying up your HTML with PHP 5](http://devzone.zend.com/article/761)" for an introduction to its use.

**EDIT:** [How can I scrape a website with invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3893375/196844)

Comment: You could use getElementsByTagName to get an html element with DOMDocument in PHP. +1 to this suggestion. More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: Hello Daniel, hello Tek, many thanks for your answers. You sugest to run the getElementsByTagName - i will have a closer look at this! The website has invalid code - unfortunatley... That said  i think it is a bad approach to do it with REGEX