# Parse html from a .dat file

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to parse some **html** that is inside an external **.dat** file.

I would normaly use the follwing code:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/cotizaciones_todas.dat');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$path = '/somepath';
$nodelist = $xpath->query($path);
echo $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/cotizaciones_todas.dat, line: 15
```

I know that the problem is the `loadHTMLFile`, I tried using `load` or `loadXML` but it's not working neither.
Any help would be appriciated.

---

**UPDATE**

To solve the problem I had to handle the errors using `libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE)`.
Now I've  a new problem, I want to count how many `<tr>` tags are inside the table. I'm using the following code:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.bvl.com.pe/includes/cotizaciones_todas.dat');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$tbody = $html->getElementsByTagName('tbody')->item(0);
$path = 'count(tr)';
$trCount = $xpath->evaluate($path,$tbody);
```

But I'm getting this error msg: `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::evaluate() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given` I already used the same code with other files and everything worked fine, but in this case it's not working, maybe because the html is broken?

Comment: Look at your server's error log. it'll have more details about the 500.

Comment: I updated my post with the log file.

Comment: The html output is not valid (927 Errors, 1167 warning(s) according to http://validator.w3.org/check), check the top voted answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893375/how-can-i-scrape-a-website-with-invalid-html

Comment: @AaronSantos you were right, the HTML was broken. However I've  anew problem now (see update).